# BigQuery GA4 - improvements to query

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics-4

I'm trying to extract some page sequence data from our BigQuery GA4 data set, with some conditions applied.

What I want is a sequence of page_view events for all sessions; that contained a specific event (called 'enquiry') in which the page_location value of the *second* page_view event matches a regex pattern.

I have the individual queries and have been able to combine them in a CTE before joining that to the main data set to pull the required data.

This is what I have come up with thus far:

In the CTE, subquery p contains the page sequence data, and subquery e contains the event data.

```
WITH sessions AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    p.ga_session_id,
    p.page_location
  FROM (
    SELECT
      event_timestamp,
      (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS ga_session_id,
      (SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') ORDER BY event_timestamp) AS row_num
    FROM
      `ga4-export.analytics_123456.events_*`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'page_view'
      AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230501' AND '20230627'
    ORDER BY
      ga_session_id,
      event_timestamp ASC) p
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS ga_session_id
    FROM
      `ga4-export.analytics_123456.events_*`
    WHERE
      event_name = 'enquiry'
      AND _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20230501' AND '20230627') e ON p.ga_session_id = e.ga_session_id
  WHERE
    row_num = 2
  GROUP BY
    1 , 2
  HAVING
    CONTAINS_SUBSTR(page_location, 'url_2')
)

SELECT
  event_timestamp,
  (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') AS ga_session_id,
  (SELECT CASE WHEN INSTR(value.string_value, "?")>0 THEN SUBSTR(value.string_value, 1, INSTR(value.string_value, "?")-1) ELSE value.string_value END FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'page_location') AS page_location_trimmed
FROM
  `ga4-export.analytics_123456.events_*` z
    INNER JOIN
  sessions s ON (SELECT value.int_value FROM UNNEST(event_params) WHERE key = 'ga_session_id') = s.ga_session_id
WHERE
  event_name = 'page_view'
ORDER BY
  1 , 2
```

This generates the output that I'm looking for, where the second page_view in each session matches the 'url_2' specified at the end of the CTE:

| event_timestamp | ga_session_id | page_location_trimmed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | url_1 |
| 2 | 1 | url_2 |
| 3 | 1 | url_3 |
| 11 | 2 | url_1 |
| 12 | 2 | url_2 |
| 100 | 3 | url_1 |

I'm relatively new to StandardSQL. My question to an experienced user is - how could I have written this better? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use more CTE's to make it more readable.
2. Remove all ORDER BYs that you don't need
3. Move filters as close to FROM as possible, e.g. instead of `HAVING ... page_location ...` use `WHERE exists(select 1 from unnest()...)`

I'm not sure whether you need to sessionize and then do all of these joins ... maybe you can find session information using window functions? E.g. `COUNTIF()` supports `OVER` so you could countif() over (partition by session id) etc.

Comment: Thanks Martin.

2. Could you point to which ORDER BY is not required? I've tried removing each of them in turn; the first two change the results, then the final one increases execution time from 6 to 22 seconds. Any idea why?

3. I'm struggling to make this work. Please could you elaborate?

I also can't wrap my head around your final point - would this mean that subquery e could be handled within p, by using COUNTIF to look for event_name = 'enquiry'? An example would be great :) Thank you!

Comment: Execution time is not a good measurement in environments with dynamic resource allocation and parallel execution, because resources might have been not available etc. Could you compare Slot Hours before and after? (And even here .... a slot is a virtual computation unit - behind the scenes there could be different kinds of CPUs, so maybe you want to sample and run the before and after both 5 times and take the average (make sure to deactivate cache))